# регулярное выражение только специальные символы

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Как составить регулярное выражение:

Выбрать только специальные символы, т.е. надо исключить любые буквы, числа и пробельные символы.
Вариант перечисление символов в [  ] не подходит.

или как создать два условия? (к примеру используя \S и \W)

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `[^\d\s\w]` не подойдёт?

Comment: Да, похоже верно, запишите в ответ.

Comment: Задача: получить все специальные символы, пунктуация нужна, re.findall(r'[^\d\s\w]+', text), на первый взгляд верно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.findall(r'[^\s\w]|_', text)` - это выражение возвращает список всех символов кроме цифр, букв и пробельных символов. `_` включена как отдельная альтернатива так как `\w` включает его в себя.

Если вы хотите группировать знаки препинания вместе: `re.findall(r'(?:[^\s\w]|_)+', text)`.

**NB** Спасибо [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182013/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) за замечания и правки в этом вопросе. Регулярные выражения не так просты.

**P.S.** При работе с группами `([^\s\w]|_)+` не работает ожидаемым образом. Сравните:

> ```
> re.findall(r'([^\s\w]|_)+'  , ',_')  -> ['_']
> re.findall(r'(?:[^\s\w]|_)+', ',_')  -> [',_']
> ```

Comment: `\d` в `[^\s\d\w]` — это плеоназм. `\w` также находит цифры.

Comment: хотелось бы не исключать символы, а именно брать те которые надо(специальные символы)

Comment: Оставил в ответе только вариант с отбором именно пунктуации включая `_`.

Comment: @KorkhovPavel Я [привёл пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1425676/182013) с использованием PyPi regex. В Python `re` нет поддержки символьных классов Юникода, поэтому нужно использовать или отрицающий шаблон, или перечисление в символьном классе.

Comment: понял. спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления всех специальных символов кроме пробельных, чтобы остались только буквы и цифры, можно использовать

```py
re.sub(r'(?:[^\w\s]|_)+', '', text)
```

**Подробности**

- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски:

  - `[^\w\s]` - любой символ, отличный от букво-цифрового *и символа нижнего подчёркивания*
  - `|` - или
  - `_` - символ нижнего подчёркивания (он ведь тоже специальный)
- `)+` - конец незахватывающей подмаски, один и более повторов.

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/99Zolr/1).

Если вы можете установить библиотеку (модуль) PyPi `regex` (`pip install regex` / `pip3 install regex` в консоли), тогда вы сможете использовать

```py
import regex
text = r"""Удалите, пожалуйста, `!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"|,.<>\/?~，！？；：（）［］【】"""
print( regex.sub(r"[\p{P}\p{S}]+", "", text) )
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsktaJEwVahSElJ6cLiC1subLiw@8KOi00XtuooXNh/Yd@FbSCRi80Xdl5sBIpu0FFIUHRQVlGNU9PS0IzX1rWNjq2utVa3UqrR0bOxi9G3r3u/p@f9nsb3e@a/3zP7/Z5Z7/d0vN/T@X7P7vd79j5umPC4YSLQJq6Cosy8Eg2IE/SKS5M0ipSiYwqqA2qBRHBtrLaSjoISEIMcp6mg@f8/AA) и [работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/99Zolr/2).

Шаблон `[\p{P}\p{S}]+` находит один и более пунктуационных (`\p{P}`) и математических (`\p{S}`) символов.